# Change a ImageView by a time interval when a button is clicked

Tags: android, imageview, counter, imagebutton

I'm trying to make a workout like App. I have a full screen `ImageView` and a `ImageButton` with a play icon. I want that when I click on the `ImageButton` the icon changes to a stop icon immediately, and the `ImageView` shows the image of the first exercise that will change after lets say 20secs to the image of the second exercise, but if a want to pause the counter I click again on the `ImageButton` to stop it.

My layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#FF5722"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Inicio"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/Boton1"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
   <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_margin="16dp"
   android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
   >
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/imagenRutina"
       android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
       />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:background="#ff5722"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
   </LinearLayout>
   <ImageButton

   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageButton"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout3"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:background="#ff5722"
   android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       />
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my java file

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.CountDownTimer;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class Rutina1Reproduccion extends AppCompatActivity {

     ImageButton mPlayButton;


     boolean isPlay = false;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rutina1_reproduccion);


    mPlayButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    background="@drawable/default"
    mPlayButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playicon);
    mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(mTogglePlayButton);
}
View.OnClickListener mTogglePlayButton = new View.OnClickListener(){
    final int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.imagengemelos,    R.drawable.imagengluteos, R.drawable.imagenbrazos};
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenRutina);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (isPlay) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playicon);
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                int i = 0;

                public void run() {
                    imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                    i++;
                    if (i > imageArray.length - 1) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);  //for interval...
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); //for initial delay..
        }else{
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopicon);

        }

        isPlay = !isPlay; // reverse
    }

};




public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(Rutina1Reproduccion.this,Rutina1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }}
```

The error I'm getting its fatal exception whenIi open the activity.

If I also want to play some sound when the `ImageButton` is clicked, how can I do it?

Comment: create the imageArray, imageView and the handler outside of the listener

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use a [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)